# Program cannot commit or quit a cell value change even after AcceptChanges

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

In my application I have a dataset that can contain many datatables. So instead of creating a separate datagridview for every table (with each table in its own tab of a tab control), I create one datagridview with some navigation buttons below it. The user can use the navigation to change which table they are viewing. So in the events for these buttons, I unbind the datagridview and then rebind it to the appropriate table, like so:

```
    thisGrid.DataSource = Nothing
    Dim tblName As String = thisTab.Text & ", " & thisCbo.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim curDataTable As DataTable = repData.BinnedTables.Tables(tblName)
    thisGrid.DataSource = curDataTable
    thisGrid.Refresh()
```

This works fine, but my problem is I need to allow the user to manually enter their own values into the datagridview. They can do this, but then if they do that, and then they navigate to a different table, then navigate back to the table with a value they had manually changed, I get error

> Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a
>   cell value change

So in the event of navigating to a different table, I first call AcceptChanges on the modified table, like so:

```
    Dim thisTable As DataTable = CType(thisGrid.DataSource, DataTable)
    For r = 0 To thisTable.Rows.Count - 1
        If thisTable.Rows(r).RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
            thisTable.AcceptChanges()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

This does work, in that `AcceptChanges()` is called when a row has been modified...but I still get the above error when it tries to set the datasource of the grid to that table.

Why am I still getting this error and how do I get around it?

Thank you!

Comment: `AcceptChanges` is essentially going to make any changes the user made invisible to you and the dataadapter.  Examine the stack trace to see who is objecting to the swap.  It sort of sounds like something from the DGV.  (and/or provide a [MCVE])

Comment: You don't need to loop over the modified rows and accept one by one. Calling AcceptChanges on the table instance accepts all modified rows in a single op

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem using a `DataSet`containing two `DataTable`. I just set the `dataGridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables["T1"]` or `"T2"` simply without calling `dataGridView1.EndEdit`.

Comment: Using `AcceptChanges` is wrong in this case. It makes your rows to go in unchanged version and hides changes from data adapter and mentioned also in the first comment.

Comment: @Plutonix - man, you were right - it had something to do with the DGV!  I ended up getting around this by checking if the table I am moving to has any modified rows, and if so I dispose and then rebuild the DGV instead of just rebind the datasource (not calling AcceptChanges).  Thank you!!

Comment: Yous should inspect the constraints defined in your `DataSet`. You might have a non nullable column that the `DataGridView` component is unable to handle when leaving. You can try with the `EnforceConstraints` property of the `DataSet` as well.